# TypeORM: IN operator not working with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, typeorm

I am trying to get a list of items using an array of ids as follows:

```
import { In } from 'typeorm';
...findBy({ _id: In(ids) })
```

Ids are set on creation:

```
@Entity()
export class Foo {
  @ObjectIdColumn({ generated: false, unique: true })
  _id: string;
  ...
}
```

However, it keeps returning an empty array.

Printing the operator shows the following:

```
FindOperator {
  '@instanceof': Symbol(FindOperator),
  _type: 'in',
  _value: [ '1', '2', '3' ],
  _useParameter: true,
  _multipleParameters: true,
  _getSql: undefined,
  _objectLiteralParameters: undefined
}
```

Comment: For mongodb use `$in` instead, check the documentation [typeorm mongodb](https://typeorm.io/mongodb#using-mongoentitymanager-and-mongorepository)

Comment: @webdev_jj this results in a typescript error `Type '{ $in: ObjectID[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ObjectID | FindOperator<ObjectID> | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '$in' does not exist in type 'ObjectID | FindOperator<ObjectID>'`

Comment: @MajedBadawi I just had the same error. It goes away when you use `MongoRepository<Foo>` instead of `Repository<Foo>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$in` operator mentioned in [typeorm mongodb](https://typeorm.io/mongodb#using-mongoentitymanager-and-mongorepository).

Example:

In your `entity`:

```
import { Entity, ObjectID, ObjectIdColumn, Column } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
class User {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  id: ObjectID;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;
}

export default User;
```

in your program:

```
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import User from "./entity/User";

createConnection()
  .then(async (connection) => {
    const repo = connection.getMongoRepository(User);

    const foo1 = new User();
    foo1.firstName = `John`;
    foo1.lastName = `Doe`;

    await repo.save(foo1);

    const users = await repo.find({
      where: {
        _id: {
          $in: [foo1.id],
        },
      },
    });

    console.log(users);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
```